# When I remove a payment profile, will I still be able do install my purchased apps?

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps

I purchased a few apps a few years ago, and my credit card expired a long time ago. So, if I close my payment profile on Google Play, will I still be able to install the apps I purchased?

Comment: Would just removing the card from your profile be satisfactory as opposed to closing the entire profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you are confusing *payment method* with *payment profile*

- If you close your *payment profile* then you **can't** install earlier purchased apps as explained [in Google payments center help](https://payments.google.com/payments/u/0/home#settings/launchWipeout=true)

> When you close this profile, the service(s) below will be canceled:
>
> - Google Play Apps
> - YouTube
> - Google Play Movies

- Instead, [Add, edit, or remove a payment method](https://support.google.com/payments/answer/6220309?hl=en&ref_topic=6209953)

Answer (score 0):

I have had an issue with changing the Google Play country and they recommended to delete the past payment profiles. I have enquired about the past purchases and they said (twice) that I will not lose them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).